# To resize ScrollView to original size

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using a scrollView having a linear layout and a ListView. initially the size of scroll view is 0 i.e height. whenever i run the code, ListView displays elements and scroll view height increases. but when ListView is emptied, size of scroll view remains as it is as it was stretched to.

I use `scrollTo(0,0)` to get to top, but i want to resize the scrollView as it was initially. can somebody tell me how to do so? thanks.

p.s: i also used `setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0,0));` but that completely removed the linear layout withen the scroll view.

Comment: It is not recommended to use a list view in scroll view.Unexpected error may occur when you scroll to the last of the list view.

Comment: http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Romain Guy comments here:

[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

As he was in charge of ListView in ANdroid developpement, I guess we should trust him ;-)

Comment: no no, i am not having trouble putting listview in scroll view, i solved that problem by manually changing size of listview items.
my problem is : scrollview size increases when list size increses. but when listview is emptied after that, i want the scroll view to resize to original size it was before. right now it remains elonganated, i.e user can scroll down even when list is cleared.

Comment: in scroll view try using layout_height as wrap content